# How do I use a third-party JS library in a react-native component?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I need to use a third-party JS library in a react native component. This library is not in npm, it’s just a minimized JS file. How do I do this?

Comment: Please give us a little bit more detail, such as the name of the library. Different libraries are packaged differently and, depending on how the library is packaged, you would use it differently.

If the library has a CommonJS or ES Modules release, then use that and `import` it into your code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you list what the module is and how you're building your react native app?